# Change JFrame's visibility from another class

Tags: java, methods, jframe, jpanel, public

I am coding a game in which I created a pause menu class `PausePanel`. In that class, I want to be able to set the `JFrame` of a different class, `MainPanel`, but whenever I make a method to do so, I get different errors/issues.

1. Class `Game` is there to show the `PausePanel` initialization.
2. Class `PausePanel` is shown because that's where I need help with the code.
3. Class `MainPanel` has the `JFrame` I want to change the visibility of.

   ```
    public class Game extends JFrame{ //Contains the game's panel
        public static void main( String[] args){
        Game g1 = new Game();
        g1.play();
    }
    public Game(){
        setVisible(true);
        //other stuff
    }
    //other methods
    private class Keys extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            setVisible(false);
            MainPanel.pause();
            PausePanel pp = new PausePanel( );
            pp.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
            pp.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT) );
            pp.setLayout( null );
   }}}



   public class PausePanel extends JFrame{ //Title Screen
       public PausePanel(){
           //other stuff
       }
       private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               if (e.getSource().equals(continu)){
                   visibility(true); <------The issue
               }
    }}} 



   public class MainPanel extends JPanel{ //Actual game
       private JPanel jp = new JPanel();
       public MainPanel(){
           //stuff
       }
       public void visibility( boolean b ){ <----This is the method I'd like to be able to use
           jp.setVisible( b );
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You can't just do `visibility(true)` on its own.  You have to provide your `PausePanel` instance with some instance of `MainPanel` (we'll call it `mp`) so that you can do `mp.visibility(true)`.  As things are, `mp` probably needs to be an instance variable of the `Game` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Game` as a control class, that listens to `PausePanel` and invokes methods in `MainPanel`. 
Alternatively you can path a reference to `MainPanel` instance to `PasuePanel`:

```
PausePanel pp = new PausePanel(mainPanel)
```